# C# MySqlReader - Unrecognized GUID format

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm reading several tables using `MySqlReader` and it works just fine until I reach a certain table that throws an exception saying `Unrecognized GUID format`. Why's that happening?

Here's the script for creating that table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mcdb`.`reactor_data`;
CREATE TABLE  `mcdb`.`reactor_data` (
  `reactorid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `max_states` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `link` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `flags` set('activate_by_touch','remove_in_fieldset') NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`reactorid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Defines reactor information.';
```

Here is the reading code:

```
foreach (var datum in new Datums("reactor_data").Populate())
        {

...

internal void PopulateInternal(string fields, string constraints)
        {
            this.Values = new List<Datum>();

            string query = string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1}{2}", fields == null ? "*" : Database.CorrectFields(fields), this.Table, constraints != null ? " WHERE " + constraints : string.Empty);

            using (MySqlDataReader reader = MySqlHelper.ExecuteReader(Database.ConnectionString, query))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        dictionary.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader.GetValue(i));
                    }

                    this.Values.Add(new Datum(this.Table, dictionary));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please show your c# code

Comment: Can you add the code that you've written for reading in the tables?

Comment: @BendEg added the reading code.

Comment: This should all be fine. Maybe the error is in you `WHERE`-clause? What happens if you comment this out? Second thing: you implemented a gread chance for sql-injection, if the user can control the input parameter :)

Comment: @BendEg I'm not using a `WHERE` clause. I'm returning all rows, but it still happens. Also, `Database.CorrectFields(fields)` takes care of any sql-injection.

Comment: If it's possible, i would drop the table and added every single column step by step and than show at which column the error appears. Sorry, i did not see: `Database.CorrectFields(fields)`

Comment: @BendEg Turns out it was the `flags` column, which is a `SET`. I tried to populate the rows without the `flags` column and it worked fine. Do you know perhaps why it fails to read the `flags` column?

Comment: I'm glad that i don't have to work with mysql until now, so i have no idea :)